# Windows 8 Desktop Application For ICSee compliant CCTV

Tags: security

I am using 10 ICSee CCTV Version 5.0 Cameras and all are ONVIF compliant

I am looking for a Windows 8 Desktop Application that can show me ICSee CCTV cameras on my Windows Desktop

Currently I am using VMS Lite and it does not recognize any ICSee CCTV camera.

VMS Lite automatically checks the CCTVS connected on local network and adds them to the desktop application

Comment: You've tagged your question as related to the [`VMS`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vms/info) family of operating systems. Could you clarify the relationship?

Comment: Corrected it. Tag VMS removed